# Dom not changed after change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is code. "ON change" working ok. But after changing value of #record_record_type element, "On focus" does not work because value of #record_record_type still the same . Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = "A";
    $("#record_record_type").on('change keypress paste focus textInput input', function() {
        if($("#record_record_type").val() == "TXT") {
            $('#numeru').html('<textarea cols="40" id="record_ttl" name="record[data]" rows="20"></textarea>');
            $("#record_record_type").val("TXT");
            current = "TXT";
        } else if($('#record_record_type').val() == "MX") {
            $('#numeru').html('<input id="record_data" name="record[data]" size="30" type="text">');
            $('#numeru').append('<label>Приоритет MX</label><input id="record_data" name="record[mx_priority]" size="30" type="text">');
            current = "MX";
        } else {
            $('#numeru').html('<input id="record_data" name="record[data]" size="30" type="text">');
        };
    });

    $("#record_data").focus(function() {
        if($("#record_record_type").val() == "A"){
            $("#new_record").validate({
                rules:{
                    "record[data]": {
                        required:true,
                        ipv4: true
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form){
                    showLoadingScreen();
                    $(form)
                        .submit()
                        .always(function(){ hideLoadingScreen() });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But

Comment: As you're creating your control through javascript, you need to use delegated event to trigger any event on it...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#record_record_type").on('change keypress paste focus textInput input', function() {
  //Put this in the end after your condition checks
  $("#record_record_type").blur();
}
```

Comment: @pahan i have added another answer see if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use instead of this line:

```
$("#record_data").focus(function() {
```

this

```
$("#record_data").on('focus', function() {
```

It will react immediately after changes.

Comment: I tried also to use $("#record_data").on('focus', function() {

It did not take any effect. When I try to use "live", I get  error 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

Comment: @pahan40 thats because live is deprecated in latest jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this maybe :

```
$("#record_record_type").on('change keypress paste focus textInput input', function() {
  //Put this in the end after your condition checks
  $("#record_record_type").blur();
  $("#record_data").focus();
}
```

Comment: That also does not help

Comment: Do you wish to record_data to be focused right after your record_record_type is triggered?

Comment: I think, that it is my fault. My explanation is very bad, sorry. ) 
I want that after focus on #record_data validation 

$("#new_record").validate({
does not work if value other than "A". But it always works because value of #record_record_type still A forever.

Comment: @pahan Alright no problem. After submit you can include this code : $("#record_record_type").val() == ''; thus your value will reset after submit